# Does AngularJS $scope not update in callback functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple snippet:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SampleController">
   <p>{{val1}}</p>
   <p>{{val2}}</p>
   <input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="update()" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.val1 = "Not updated";
    $scope.val2 = "Not updated";

    $scope.update = function () {
        $scope.val1 = "Updated outside!";

        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.val2 = "Update inside!";
        }, 1);
    };
}]);
```

snippet also in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataspiazzi/re25x0cg/2/).

If I click in the update button only the value val1 is updated in the html. How to fix that? But most importantly, why is this happening?

**PS:** setTimeout is just a simplification of the problem. In fact the question is about any custom components that has callback functions.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` doesn't trigger a digest cycle, so no the view will not update. Angular comes with a built in `$timeout` module - use that and a digest cycle will execute and your view will update.

To use:

```
app.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() { $scope.val2 = "see?" }, 5000);
}]);
```

Comment: Nice, but if i'm using something else, like jQuery.ajax.success or $http.get. Or something that there is no hack (like '$timeout') by angularjs?

Comment: Well, `http.get` will trigger a digest cycle - so your safe there. Basically, anything outside of Angular modules won't trigger the cycle, so you'll need to work around it with hacks or write your own angular module

Comment: Is there somehow to notify 'digest cycle' that a scope change was maded?

Comment: You can force digest cycles with `$scope.$apply()` - but that's a hack and errors can happen because of it - `$timeout` is generally a safe way to force a digest cycle.

Comment: I would read: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: I made a update. If you comply, I can make this answer as correct.

Comment: But your edit is wrong - you shouldn't use `$scope.apply()` to force a digest when there is an angular module specifically to not do that. You should only force the digest cycle if you *have* to.